# Is it possible to create index on mongoDB during createCollection com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase.createCollection(

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase in Java. I would like to create an new collection with an Index using MongoDatabase.createCollection(....

My current implementation:

```
mongoDatabase.createCollection("employees");
mongoDatabase.getCollection("employees")
     .createIndex(Indexes.ascending("empId"), new IndexOptions().unique(true));
```

Is it possible to merge two statements above into one?

Comment: When you create the index it also creates the collection (if the collection doesn't exist).

Comment: Is it so, you mean to say that statement mongoDatabase.createCollection("employees"); is not required?

Comment: Simply `mongoDatabase.getCollection("employees").createIndex(...);`. There is no need for `createCollection` - unless you like to use an [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an index on a non-existing collection, the command also creates an empty collection and the index. I verified it in the `mongo` shell as well.

```
mongoDatabase.getCollection("employees")
     .createIndex(Indexes.ascending("empId"), new IndexOptions().unique(true));

// or

employeeCollection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("empId"), new IndexOptions().unique(true));
```

Comment: If you want to create the collection and the index within a transaction, this feature is available in MongoDB 4.4+ version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way of doing both in a single API call.  But that being said, is there any particular reason why you want them done in a single method call?  Presumably this portion of your code would not be so sensitive to transactional issues such as the create collection working but index creation failing.

If you are using Mongo 4+ along with the Spring Mongo library, you may place both statements into a single method and then annotate it with `@Transactional`:

```java
@Transactional
public void createCollectionAndIndex() {
    mongoDatabase.createCollection("employees");
    mongoDatabase.getCollection("employees")
        .createIndex(Indexes.ascending("empId"), new IndexOptions().unique(true));
}
```

Then, either all logic succeeds, or some exception happens and everything gets rolled back.